# Number Formatting (input mask) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, number-formatting

I'm trying to format numbers in a text field like so:

123,456,789

I know that there are a lot of jQuery plugins to do this, however, they all change the actual value. I just want it to look formatted, and not be sent formatted.

For example, if I type in `23845` into my text field, I want it to visually convert to `23,845`, but when I send the form I want it to send as `23845`.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? All other solutions I've seen change the actual submitted value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the masks plugin do not change the value but only the display : http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/mask

[edit] within the list of all the plugins, i've used this one on my code : https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask ([edit 2]  <strike>and worked as you want</strike>  i've checked the code where i used it and the default behavior is that it sends the mask **with** the value, you need to use an option to unmask as i've said in my comment)

Comment: Finally got it working, but it has the problem of sending the masked value with form submission. Maybe I'm missing something... =(

Comment: it depends on the input mask plugin you choose. Some have the option to unmask (but contrary to what i said - sorry - it seems not to be the default behavios). Have a look at `unmask` solution here : https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/issues/8

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've decided that inputmask isn't exactly what I want (don't like how it has the placeholders and fixed characters there and I can't figure out how to take them off), however you've pointed me in the right direction and I eventually found MeioMask. Works great. I unset the masks with the .submit() event.

http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/

Comment: @Ryan: glad you found a solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on('keyup', '.test', function() {
            var x = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
        });
    </script>

    <form>
       <input class="test" type="text" />
    </form>
```